# How can I (dynamically) clean my pandas column, with making every class as new column with the corresponding values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am pre-processing data for analytics. But I am kind of stuck with the pre-processing.

**My data (5 data rows, see the numbers on the left side)**

```
1   "#3,185 in Beauty &amp; Personal Care (See Top 100 in Beauty &amp; Personal Care)
.zg_hrsr { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none; }
.zg_hrsr_item { margin: 0 0 0 10px; }
.zg_hrsr_rank { display: inline-block; width: 80px; text-align: right; }

    #11
    inÂ Men's Foil Shavers

    #11
    inÂ Men's Foil Shavers
    "
2   "#874 in Beauty &amp; Personal Care (See Top 100 in Beauty &amp; Personal Care)

.zg_hrsr { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none; }
.zg_hrsr_item { margin: 0 0 0 10px; }
.zg_hrsr_rank { display: inline-block; width: 80px; text-align: right; }

    #6
    inÂ Men's Foil Shavers


    #6
    inÂ Men's Foil Shavers
    "
3   "#266 in Beauty &amp; Personal Care (See Top 100 in Beauty &amp; Personal Care)

.zg_hrsr { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none; }
.zg_hrsr_item { margin: 0 0 0 10px; }
.zg_hrsr_rank { display: inline-block; width: 80px; text-align: right; }

    #1
    inÂ Men's Foil Shavers

    #1
    inÂ Men's Foil Shavers
    "
4   "#652 in Beauty &amp; Personal Care (See Top 100 in Beauty &amp; Personal Care)

.zg_hrsr { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none; }
.zg_hrsr_item { margin: 0 0 0 10px; }
.zg_hrsr_rank { display: inline-block; width: 80px; text-align: right; }

    #3
    inÂ Men's Foil Shavers


    #3
    inÂ Men's Foil Shavers
    "
5   "#124,111 Paid in Kindle Store (See Top 100 Paid in Kindle Store)

.zg_hrsr { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none; }
.zg_hrsr_item { margin: 0 0 0 10px; }
.zg_hrsr_rank { display: inline-block; width: 80px; text-align: right; }

    #2
    inÂ Borneo Travel Guides

    "
```

I want to have this data in a 'Tidy format' for data analysis.

- I need the numbers after the hashtag ('#')
- I need the corresponding category (e.g.: in Beauty, Men's foil Shavers

Optimal would be an dynamical solution, since row 5 (for example) is adding new categories (e.g.:Paid in Kindle Store, inÂ Borneo Travel Guides).

**Desired outcome:**

```
 Beauty &amp        Men's Foil Shavers  Paid in Kindle store   Â Borneo Travel Guides
3,185              11                      nan                     nan
  874               6                      nan                     nan
  266               1                      nan                     nan
  652               3                      nan                     nan
  nan             nan                      124,111                 2
```

You will see that the difficulty comes in with row 5, where new categories are introduced.

**What have I tried?**

I tried to split the column after the '#', and take the first X characters.

```
x = df['Column'].str.split('#', expand=True).rename(columns=lambda x: f"Column_{x+1}")
df = pd.concat([df, x], axis=1)
```

The result is:

1. Multiple columns, containing the numbers and categories (e.g.: 300 in Beauty)
2. Unfortunately, the columns have mixed values (e.g.: 300 in Beauty, 200 in inÂ Borneo Travel Guides).
3. This means that I cannot process the data properly, since the columns containing multiple categories.

**Future Steps:** The only thing that I can think of, is 'hardcode' the categories, e.g.:

- Column Beauty = If Beauty in column_X, then take the number, else NAN. (I guess that this will lead to a columns Beauty, containing only numbers if it is in the category.

Hope that someone can help me!

**Many thanks in advance**